# find biggest hash value regarding each key in perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have a file with this structure

```
>test1
MATRTQARGA 
>test2
MRIIEGKLQLQG
>test1
 MATRTQARGAVVELLYAFESGNEEIKKIASSML
```

in the result I want

```
>test2
MRIIEGKLQLQG
>test1
MATRTQARGAVVELLYAFESGNEEIKKIASSML
```

I was thinking about a **hash structure** which keys are the lines with > and the next line after each >line would be the value then for each key I some how print the string with longest length , but since hash structures can not have duplicate keys I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need duplicate keys, you just have to store the current longest value for each key, and replace it when you get a longer one:

```
my %longest;
my $curkey;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^>/) {
    $curkey = $_;
    $curkey =~ s/^.//; # Remove '>' prefix;
    next;
  } 
  if (length($_) > length($longest{$curkey})) {
    $longest{$curkey} = $_;
  }
}
```

Comment: :why it doesnt work when I try to read from a file with the same fashion

Answer (score -1):

another, less intuitive way

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = ">"; # local not really needed here, as its in the global scope..
my %unqs;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if (m/^\s*>/);
    my @arr = grep { not m/>|^\s*$/ } split(/\n/);
    $unqs{$arr[0]} = $arr[1] if (length($arr[1]) > length($unqs{$arr[0]}));
}

print Dumper(\%unqs);

__DATA__
>test1
MATRTQARGA 
>test2
MRIIEGKLQLQG
>test1
MATRTQARGAVVELLYAFESGNEEIKKIASSML
```

now you can use `%unqs` hash and print it to a file, you will end up with what you want.